# Spring Security login/logout problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring 4.3.3 and I am trying to implement login/logout functionalities for my application. The issue I am having is that if I log in and log back out again straight away all works as expected. I am taken to the login page at URL:login?logout with a successfully logged out message in the login box. However, if I login and navigate to another page then logout I am again correctly taken to the login page with a successfully logged out message in the login box, but when I click login I am not logged in. Instead I an taken to the login with URL: login with no message and I need to click login a second time to be logged in. Below is some of the code I am using

security.xml

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/forgot**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/reset**" security="none" />
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<security:http 
    auto-config="false" 
    use-expressions="true">
    <headers><cache-control/></headers>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/suppliers**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/games**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/clients**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/servers**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logs**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

<!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 

        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" 
        login-processing-url="/auth/login_check" />

    <security:logout 
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/login"
        logout-url="/login?logout"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
    <!-- Default lifeTime 2 weeks can be configured -->
    <!--<remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret"/>-->
</security:http>
```

Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView login( @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus sessionStatus) throws IOException {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
    }

    if (logout != null) {

        HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        session= request.getSession(false);

        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }

        //sessionStatus.setComplete();
        //request.getSession(false).invalidate();

        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");
    return model;

}
```

login.jsp

```
<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/auth/login_check?targetUrl=${targetUrl}' />" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="emailError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;"></div> 
            <label for="email">Email
                <input  class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email">
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password
                <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
        </div>
            Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" />
            <input id="login"class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
            <div><a id="forgotPass">forgot password</a></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, Not sure. I was just following a tutorial and it had the 2 asterisks. Can you explain why /logs** will never hit??

Comment: Shouldn't you have "/auth" added to the Permit All list?

Comment: @dur, since the form method is being set with auth/login_check, will Spring handle these requests as being mentioned as "login-processing-url"? Another thought is that the redirect happens because it has targetUrl=somereference, will the config be modified with wildcard match login-processing-url="/auth/login_check*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your security configuration, I'm not sure if you're using the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` or not. I see you're manually expiring all cookies when logging out:

```
 for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
     cookie.setMaxAge(0);
 }
```

Unless you have other cookies you manually set in your application, the session cookie will be deleted by default, since you configured it to do so:

```
<security:logout 
    ...
    delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

My guess is that you're also clearing the CSRF token cookie, so the login-page that gets rendered without the token. Submitting the form may fail silently due to mismatch of CSRF, taking you back to the login page. This time, the CSRF value will be set again and subsequent login attempt succeeds.

Comment: Hi @frederik-heremans Thanks for your response. I think this was the problem. i removed the code from the controller that was expiring the session and cookies and it works as expected. However i have noticed another issue. Once i have logged out. If I manually edit the URL I am correctly redirected to the login page but if i click back i am taken to the previous page and still logged in.

Comment: As @dur mentioned, "Spring Security does it for you, you already configured it.". Either you use the spring-security logout mechanism (which handles the session invalidation for your) OR you implement your own "logout" logic (which you are doing) in a controller - here you still need to invalidate the session. This will trigger the redirect to the login-page, since no valid credentials are present and spring-security kicks in...